# Error while parsing '%' character in XML on Android 2.3.5

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

Following text 
[

```
fetched using HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(), 
parsed using XmlPullParser.getText(), 
sent as String (sText) to my Activity and 
loaded with WebView.loadData(sText, "text/html", null)
```

]

```
&lt;p&gt;My friend scored 100% in the exam.&lt;/p&gt;
```

is not shown in my activity (on Android 2.3.5 device) 
[Error thrown is "Web page not available ....", but upon reading the subsequent text I can confirm that the text has been fetched to the device], 
whereas

```
&lt;p&gt;My friend scored 100 percent in the exam.&lt;/p&gt;
```

is displayed correctly.
Please note that both of the above are displayed fine on Android 4.1.1.
Any pointers would really help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using %25 in place of %, did the trick....